# Type Theory with no Base Types

Tags: reference-request, type-theory

Is there any work in type theory where no base types are assumed, e.g., that there are only function types in place ($t_1 \to t_2$ is a type whenever $t_1$ and $t_2$ are types)?

If not, are there specific reasons for that?

Comment: Are you allowing the empty model where there are no types? If so, some adjustments would need to be made, akin to those for [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/).

Comment: I'm more interested in models where there's at least one type (hence infinitely many types?) -- just that no type is a base type.

Comment: That doesn't give infinitely many types (assuming only $\to$ as a type constructor): there is a model where the only type is the unit type. Whether that's the only finite model probably depends on your axioms.

Answer (score 4):

[System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) seems to satisfy your criteria, provided you allow other type constructors. Types are constructed from $\rightarrow$ and $\forall$. There are no base types like those of, say, system T (i.e. $\mathsf{nat}$).

Answer (score 3):

In many formal systems we work with *metavariables*, which are meta-level symbols which stand for unknown, arbitrary or yet-to-be-determined entities. For instance, in propositional calculus we say things like "$A \land B$ is equivalent to $B \land A$" -- here $A$ and $B$ are metavariables standing for any formulas.

We can do the same thing in type theory. From your examples I surmise that you have in mind simple types, so let us stay with those. It is perfectly OK, and even useful, to consider types in which metavariables occur, as then you can say things like "$\lambda (x : A \times B). (\pi_2 x, \pi_1 x)$ is an isomorphism from $A \times B$ is isomorphic to $B \times A$". In your question you yourself used the metavariables $t_1$ and $t_2$ when you spoke of the type $t_1 \to t_2$.

Without metavariables and without base types the type theory becomes trivial because we cannot form *any* types at all.

Comment: Don't you still have things like product or sum of an empty family of types? Not that it makes for anything nontrivial, but...

Comment: Firstly, we're in the realm of simple types so there are no families. But if we did consider dependent types, how would you get the empty family without having the empty type first?

Comment: Definitely I am in no position to say anything competent about that, but I was thinking about something less sophisticated than dependent types, so probably I should not use the word "family" but rather, say, "tuple".

Specifically I was thinking about a programming language which has possibility to produce the product type or the sum type of any tuple of types, including the empty tuple. Is not there a syntactic counterpart of such a thing?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what if we keep the metavariables but posit no base types? Would it still be trivial? For example, what if we speculate that the space of types is non-empty, and the only type constructors are of the form $t_1\to t_2$, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are metavariables? It seems to me that we haven't committed to base types here. Would this be still trivial? Or do we need dependant types to accommodate such a move?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, you could posit a product operation that takes a list of types, and in ML and Haskell do precisely that, so that `a * b * c` is a primitive ternary product, which is neither `(a * b) * c` nor `a * (b * c)`. If you allow the product of an empty list that's just a roundabout way of positing a primitive type, namely the unit type. ML does not allow it, Haskell does.

Comment: @qk11: when you work with metavariables you must always keep track of which ones are currently being used. It's a bit like polynomials, you need to know in which variables the polynomials are formed. Without any primitive types and $\to$ as the only type constructor, you cannot form any type without having at least one metavariable. Note also that metavariables may be construed as "unspecified primitive types", so a lot of what we're discussing is about what point of view you want to take.